# L' « (over)sharenting » : que pense-t-on de la proposition « surpartage parental » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, néologismes, préfixes

Dans un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/vivre/famille/201902/11/01-5214318-photos-sur-les-reseaux-sociaux-ces-enfants-qui-disent-non.php) sur le respect du droit des enfants à la vie privée, entre autres, j'apprends l'existence du [néologisme](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4083) « (over)[sharenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharenting) » (mot-valise : [*over-sharing*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overshare#English), [*parenting*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parenting)) pour décrire « the [overuse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overuse) of [social media](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26502881) by parents to [share](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26532812) content based on their children » (Wikipédia, *sharenting*), traduisant « cette obsession narcissique des parents de vouloir partager le quotidien de leurs enfants comme ils partagent le leur » ([Le Monde](https://www.lemonde.fr/big-browser/article/2017/04/18/a-quel-point-publier-des-photos-de-ses-enfants-sur-facebook-est-il-dangereux_5113202_4832693.html), via Termium). On propose d'exprimer la notion par « [surpartage parental](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&srchtxt=SHARENTING&i=1&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) » (Termium, Bureau de la traduction,  Direction de la normalisation terminologique, 2018), en préfixant partage avec [*sur-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sur-) pour exprimer l'excès et l'adjectif [*parental*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parental) pour qualifier de qui relève l'action.

---

- Pourquoi considère-t-on objectivement qu'il s'agit là d'une bonne
  proposition ou non : s'agit-il d'un bon choix de préfixe, du terme
  préfixé et de l'épithète ; est-ce clair et cohérent en français ;
  a-t-on une autre proposition que l'on juge meilleure ; peut-on
  composer en un seul mot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectivement, aux premiers abords, l'expression **surpartage parental** semble assez difficile à comprendre.

Mais en la décortiquant, on trouve :

> surpartage

Avec **partage**, en référence aux différents partages de photos, vidéos, ... sur les réseaux sociaux (facebook, snapchat, instagram, ...)

Et le prefix **sur** pour signifier *trop* (surpopulation, suralimentation, ...).

> parental

Est un adjectif signifiant littéralement **des parents**, implicitement, par rapport à leurs enfants.

Ce qui nous donne au final, **Trop de partages sur les réseaux sociaux, de la part des parents, sur leurs enfants**.

Pour ma part cette expression est tout à fait correcte, et je ne vois pas trop comment la réduire à un seul mot. D'ailleurs, en anglais, le mot est séparé en 2 avec un "-" : **over-sharenting**